# How to 'svn export' the *unchanged* current version without network access?

Tags: svn

**Background:** Before committing a change, I want to compile the *old* version (without changes) and the *new* version of the program and compare their output, like this:

```
svn export -r HEAD . /target/for/old-version
svn export         . /target/for/new-version
... compile and run code in /target/for/old-version
... compile and run code in /target/for/new-version
... compare results
```

My problem is that 'svn export -r HEAD' accesses the main repository over the network --- which is slow.  But SVN keeps the current (unchanged) version on the disk: 'svn cat file' shows the *old* content of the file *without* access to the network.

How can I achieve the result of 'svn export -r HEAD' by accessing only data on disk, not via the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svn export -r BASE . /target/for/old-version

I didn't test this not using the network. It shoudln't.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That's even better than the previous solution.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot get at the head version, but only at the working copy's base version (the one you updated to last):

1. Make a copy of your working copy.
2. Revert in that copy.

You're done.